# Database operations on Hashmap using spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I get some thousands of data from webservice call. (It would be id and version number, list of objects)

I am required to check if the record exists for an id in the database.If it does and the version number mismatches , I need to update the table
or else insert a new record.

What do you think is the optimal solution

1. Fetch the records from DB and cache it. Remove the records which are matching from the list. Prepare a list which requires update and
   the others which require insert and then call out procedure to insert and update accordingly
   (Once I prepare the list, it could be relatively lesser records)
2. Loop through each one of the record I receive from the webservice and pass the id and version to a procdure which carries out insert/update
   based on the need
   (Using connection pool but for each record, I would be calling the procedure)

Which do you think is better approach of the two...or do you think of a better solution than these two

Limitiations to technologies to be used:
Spring Jdbc 2.x ,Java 1.7,Sybase database

No ORM technologies available.

Can I use jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() for calling a procedure

Answer (score 0):

**First option is better than option 2.**

No operation is costlier then network latency between application server and database server.
Thumb rule is lesser the call , better the performance.

Not sure, contraints with sysbase, but even if *you can process 5-10 records in each SP call* , that will be even more better than processing single record everytime.